# Wrap latex environment

Tags: listings, environments

I'm a beginning latex user. I have some programming code in my document which I format using the lstlisting environment from the package listings.

However this still allows the code segments to be split into two pieces when placed near the end of a page.

To fix this I also use a figure environment for code.
This causes an often recurring pattern:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{lstlisting}
..code..
\end{lstlisting}
\end{figure}
```

How can I define a new environment for this pattern?
I tried:

```
\newenvironment{mylisting}
{
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{lstlisting}
}
{
\end{lstlisting}
\end{figure}
}
```

However using this environment gave errors all over.

Comment: See also: [macros - Defining a new environment extending a verbatim environment - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114643/defining-a-new-environment-extending-a-verbatim-environment)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the `listings` package needs to make all kinds of changes to the internals of LaTeX in order to evaluate the contents of the `lstlisting` environment in a non-LaTeX way.  In particular it shuts down expansion of control sequences starting with `\` so the end code to your `mylisting` environment gets passed right by.

If all you want to do is have a listing in a float, you can do

```
\begin{lstlisting}[float=h]
...
\end{lstlisting}
```

You might find [some of these questions about the listings package on the TeX SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/listings) useful as well.