# Defining a new environment extending a verbatim environment

Tags: macros, environments, verbatim

Why is it not possible to define a new environment that extends a `verbatim` environment?
Consider, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{myverbatim}{\tiny\begin{verbatim}}{\end{verbatim}}
\begin{document}
\begin{myverbatim}
  test
\end{myverbatim}
\end{document}
```

Compiling with `pdflatex` gives the error:

```
Runaway argument?
^^M  test^^M\end{myverbatim}^^M\end{document}^^M^^M
! File ended while scanning use of \@xverbatim.
<inserted text> 
                \par
```

(A motivation for this question can be found here: "[Format a verbatim paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113906/format-a-verbatim-paragraph)". From which it should be clear that I cannot use the `listings` or `fancyvrb` packages)

It would be nice with a basic and perhaps more detailed explanation (for this particular case and the reason for the error message) than what is given in, for instance, this discussion: "[Why doesn’t verbatim work within...](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-verbwithin)", and if there could be workarounds for simple cases like the one in this example..

**Edit1:**

Based on the answers so far, I feel that I need to be more precise about my case: I am trying to get the following code to work somehow (Confer with "[Format a verbatim paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113906/format-a-verbatim-paragraph)" for more details)

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\begingroup
  \catcode`|=0
  \catcode`[=1
  \catcode`]=2
  \catcode`\{=12
  \catcode`\}=12
  \catcode`\\=12
  |gdef|myvr@xverbatim#1\end{myverbA}[#1|end[myverbA]]
|endgroup
\newenvironment{myverbA}{%
  \let\@xverbatim=\myvr@xverbatim
  \verbatim
}{%
}
\makeatother
\newenvironment{myverbB}{\tiny\begin{myverbA}}{\end{myverbA}}
\begin{document}
\begin{myverbB}
  test
\end{myverbB}
\end{document}
```

**Edit2:**

Based on `egreg`'s answer, I tried the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\begingroup
  \catcode`|=0
  \catcode`[=1
  \catcode`]=2
  \catcode`\{=12
  \catcode`\}=12
  \catcode`\\=12
  |gdef|myvr@xverbatim#1\end{myverbA}[#1|end[myverbA]]
|endgroup
\newenvironment{myverbA}{%
  \let\@xverbatim=\myvr@xverbatim
  \verbatim
}{%
}
\newenvironment{myverbB}
  {\preto\verbatim@font{\tiny}
   \myverbA}
  {\endmyverbA}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{myverbB}
  test
\end{myverbB}
\end{document}
```

which produces the error:

```
Runaway argument?
^^M  test^^M\end{myverbB}^^M\end{document}^^M^^M
! File ended while scanning use of \@xverbatim.
<inserted text> 
                \par
```

Comment: Instead of editing your question again and again you should ask a follow up question. Provided answers with upvotes may not reloaded to your follow up question.

Comment: It is not actually an edit of the question.. It is a comment to `egreg`'s solution, that would not fit into the comment under under his answer :) I don't feel it would be appropriate to post it as a follow-up question..

Comment: For reference: special case of [Defining environments based on other ones: What's the right way? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14683/defining-environments-based-on-other-ones-whats-the-right-way).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The main problem with using your definition of `myverbatim` can be defined in terms of a combination of scope and macro replacement. That is, something that starts with

```
\begin{<some-env>}
```

is expected to end with

```
\end{<some-env>}
```

If it doesn't, there's a problem, since the scope is not clearly defined. In your case, you start it with

```
\begin{myverbatim}
```

which is internally replaced with (removing the font change to `\tiny` for now)

```
\begin{verbatim}
```

Now, since you're in the `verbatim` environment (that is, a successful call was made to `\begin{verbatim}`), LaTeX starts gobbling up contents and printing them as-is *until* it arrives at a single line of code that resembles

```
\end{verbatim}
```

That's just how the `verbatim` environment works. It it looking for the stopping point. However, this never happens since the replacement of `\end{myverbatim}` (in your code) to `\end{verbatim}` (as per your definition) never occurs within the `verbatim` environment; `verbatim` doesn't perform the replacement of macros with their definitions. As such, TeX just keeps on scanning, producing what is considered a "Runaway argument" error.

Taking the above into account, a broad view on the replacement leaves your MWE to resemble (I've added a comment):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{myverbatim}{\tiny\begin{verbatim}}{\end{verbatim}}
\begin{document}
\tiny\begin{verbatim}% Replacement text for \begin{myverbatim}
  test
\end{myverbatim}% No replacement since you're in the verbatim environment
\end{document}
```

Clearly the above doesn't start and end with the same environment.

If you want to have more flexibility with `verbatim`, use the [`verbatim` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/verbatim) which allows you to do the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}% http://ctan.org/pkg/verbatim
\newenvironment{myverbatim}%
  {\endgraf\tiny\verbatim}%
  {\endverbatim}
\begin{document}
Some text before.
\begin{myverbatim}
test
test
\end{myverbatim}
Some text after.
\end{document}
```

The `verbatim` package is a means to obtain your desired solution, just like [`fancyvrb`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) and [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) would be. Of course, a more rudimentary implementation (specific to your case) would be to merely change the font used by `verbatim` - stored in the macro `\verbatim@font`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\verbatim@font}{\tiny\ttfamily}
\makeatother
```

Sure you can just precede the `verbatim` environment with `\tiny` and it will work just as well, but `\verbatim@font` is called within the `verbatim` environment, and therefore is constrained to only function there, not outside of it.

Comment: Thanks for the nice reply! How can I use your suggestion for my case? See "Edit" section at the end of my question. If I write  `\newenvironment{myverB}{\endgraf\tiny\myverbA}%  {\endmyverbA}` I get the error `\begin{myverbB} ended by \end{document}`

Comment: @HåkonHægland: I guess [egreg's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114672/5764) addresses your this concern...

Answer (score 13):

It doesn't work because after

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{myverbatim}{\tiny\begin{verbatim}}{\end{verbatim}}
\begin{document}
\begin{myverbatim}
  test
```

`\` is no longer an escape character it acts verbatim just typestting a `\`. so this:

```
\end{myverbatim}
```

is not a command to end the environment, it is just more text, and so is this:

```
\end{document}
```

and TeX hits the end of file and things have gone wrong.

A normal `verbatim` ends because it looks especially for the string `\end{verbatim}`
and stops. That string is not in your document.

The `verbatim` and `fancyvrb` packages give facilities for defining verbatim-like environments.

Comment: You say the string `\end{verbatim}` is not in my document. But I used it in the definition of `myverbatim`..

Comment: Sorry, I see that my question has been answered by `Werner`

Answer (score 7):

The problem is the timing where the `\tiny` command is issued. It can't go before `\verbatim` without a preceding `\par`, but it can't go after it either.

So you have to change the definition of `\verbatim@font`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{myverbA}
  {\verbatim}
  {\endverbatim}
\newenvironment{myverbB}
  {\preto\verbatim@font{\tiny}
   \myverbA}
  {\endmyverbA}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[3]% no \par is issued
\begin{myverbB}
  test
\end{myverbB}
\lipsum*[3]
\begin{myverbA}
another test
\end{myverbA}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You may also want to look at the `fancyvrb` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\newenvironment{myverbA}
  {\Verbatim}
  {\endVerbatim}
\newenvironment{myverbB}
  {\myverbA[fontsize=\tiny]}
  {\endmyverbA}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[3]% no \par is issued
\begin{myverbB}
  test
\end{myverbB}
\lipsum*[3]
\begin{myverbA}
another test
\end{myverbA}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer! I tried to implement your solution, see end of my question..

Comment: @HåkonHægland Where, in my solution, do you find catcode settings? Why should you want to follow that complicated route?

Comment: @HåkonHægland Now I see more clearly the matter. No, you can't define a verbatim environment in terms of another one if you follow your route, so all you can do is defining `myverbB` in the same way you define `myverbA` and adding the redefinition of `\verbatim@font`.

Answer (score 3):

An answer can be found here [Command for special text with reserved LaTeX symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111966/command-for-special-text-with-reserved-latex-symbols/111976#111976) or, if you don't mind the result in boxes (I mean LaTeX box, not a bordered box), you can use the `verbatimbox` package with an optional argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbbox}[\tiny]
This is tiny \verbatim
\end{verbbox}
\theverbbox
\end{document}
```